# How to solve Post/Get Method use in postman with Magento controller?

Tags: magento2.3.1, post-data, get

I am using Magento controller URL with Postman.
When I select **Get Method** in postman then it runs perfectly with execute method.
But when I use the **Post Method** that time it breaks from the `execute()` method. It means for the Post method, the execute method, not works.

Any idea for this issue? 
my code is

```
<?php
namespace Lucent\SocialLogin\Controller\Login;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{



    protected $_customer;
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    )
    {

        $this->data = $_REQUEST;
        print_r($this->data);
        $this->_customer = $customer;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }




    public function execute()
    {
        //$postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        //print_r($this->getRequest()->getParam('test'));    
        //print_r($this->data);
        //print_r($postData);
        echo '1';
        die();

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: try this `$this->getRequest()->getPostValue();` also try to print

`$this->getRequest()->getParams();`

Comment: if that doesn't work try using `Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface`

Comment: tried both but not goes into execute function mate

Comment: you are using this code for frontend or backend? also share the screenshot of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution here. When I trying with $.post() method that time no need of form_key.

But, When I  trying with var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); with post method then form_key mandatory so that is why $_POST data not getting so quit from it.

Thanks all whoever supports.